# $_Get not getting url id

Tags: php, get

****fixed*********

```
echo "<li><a href=\"product_display?id=$id\">" . $row['iname'] . "</a></li>";
```

what is missing ?

.php

/facepalm

---

I can't seem to get the id value to pass to the $_GET. I've tried adding sessions and all kinds of stuff.

Even when I just do a `print_r($GET)` by itself it gives me :

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete

This is not for production, but a project so I'm not to worried about injections ect..
I've use GET with old php mysql syntax and it works, just not sure what the problem is. Alos no the code is barbaric so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Page 1 :

```
<?php
require('lib/inc/db_inc.php');

$sql = "SELECT items.itemID, items.iname, items.idesc, items.iprice,iimg.imgURL FROM items JOIN iimg ON items.itemID = iimg.pid WHERE items.itype = 'usb_controllers'";

$stmt = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

$id = $row['itemID'];

echo "<div class=\"prodMain\">";
echo "<div class=\"img\">";
echo "<a href=\"#\"><img src=\"" . $row['imgURL'] ."\"/></a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href=\"product_display?id=$id\">" . $row['iname'] . "</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href=\"#\">" . $row['idesc'] . "</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href=\"#\">" . $row['iprice'] . "</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

page 2 :

```
 <?php
require('../lib/inc/db_inc.php');
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    die("missing query parameter");
}
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($id === '') {
    die("Invalid query parameter");
}

$sql = "SELECT items.itemID, items.iname, items.idesc, items.iprice,iimg.imgURL FROM items JOIN iimg ON items.itemID = iimg.pid  WHERE itemID = '$id'";

$stmt = $db->query($sql);

$row = $stmt->fetch();

echo print_r($row);
?>
```

db_inc.php

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=******;dbname=*****', '*********', '********');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: does this work? : <?php print_r($_GET) ?>

Comment: according to this page - http://kb.mozillazine.org/The_page_isn't_redirecting_properly - the message is due when your page redirects you in an endless loop. If this is all the code in your pages, check `../lib/inc/db_inc.php` for an endless loop. Most likely missing a closing bracket `}` or a for loop that never increases.

Comment: my db_inc.php is edited in OP

Comment: SO dumb   LOL 

echo "<li><a href=\"product_display?id=$id\">" . $row['iname'] . "</a></li>";

what is missing ?

.php LOL 

SOrry for wasting your time and thank you for the info !

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
$sql = "SELECT items.itemID, items.iname, items.idesc, items.iprice, iimg.imgURL FROM items JOIN iimg ON items.itemID = iimg.pid WHERE itemID = '$id'";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
```

has a **vulnerability** for **SQL Injection**. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
So you should rewrite it like

```
$sql = "SELECT items.itemID, items.iname, items.idesc, items.iprice, iimg.imgURL FROM items JOIN iimg ON items.itemID = iimg.pid WHERE itemID = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question (why isn't $_GET working for them), and the question does specifically say that they are not worried about injections. That being said, a reminder doesn't hurt, but I believe a comment would fit this better than an answer.